# Error debugging CGLIB FastClass on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, reflection, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug an java eclipse project with some problem!

I'm starting using [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) to make faster reflection calls using the index metod.

example

```
FastClass fastClass = FastClass.create(getClass());
int index = fastClass.getIndex("methodName", new Class[] { Object.class });
fastClass.invoke(index, this, new Object[] { obj } );
```

now when i try to put a breakpoint into a class that is called by fastreflection method this is the eclipse output.

[image: Breakpoint output]

I try to change compiler option on generate line number with no results.

I also upload an eclipse project (built with Juno version) that replicates the problem!!

http://www.filefactory.com/file/4zryz3gjgbyh/n/FastDebug.rar

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "resolved"(understand) the problem, but it is not a problem with Eclipse. When you launch
the program this line: FastClass.create(ReflectionTarget.class); ends up
creating an entirely new version of the compiled class removing all
non-essential stuff from the classfile to make it "fast" - that includes all
the line number / debug infos, which means the breakpoint cannot be set in it.

http://cglib.sourceforge.net/xref/net/sf/cglib/core/package-summary.html

There's no javadoc and you need to read the source but now i understand this is not a 
problem but a feature of this method to make fast reflection!

Comment: Did you also find a workaround to get around it ... so that you may set breakpoints in Eclipse?